# What is the "Model TA-M" I marked in yellow in the table?

Tags: general-aviation, airport, meteorology, aeronautical-information

What is the "Model TA-M" I marked in yellow in the table? I think it represents a weather chart, but I don't know if it's an abbreviation or what the explanation is. The table image was taken from the AIP Turkey document for Adana LTAF airport.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Model TA-M* is another briefing and flight planning weather report used by military.

---

The [Turkish State Meteorological Service (MGM)](https://mgm.gov.tr) prepares weather data for civil and military aviation users. These data are computed from various sources, and formatted and displayed using a software application called METCAP+, developed by this service:

[image]

([Source](https://www-cdn.eumetsat.int/files/2020-04/pdf_metcap_plus_manual.pdf))

The output can be formatted to correspond to TAF, METAR, SIGMET, etc. In addition METCAP+ can provide data conforming to the NATO model TA-M. From [METCAP+ User Manual](https://www-cdn.eumetsat.int/files/2020-04/pdf_metcap_plus_manual.pdf#page=168), a partial view of this form:

[image]